# earthEngine expression and ternary operator: why does evaluate false value when always true?

Tags: google-earth-engine, conditional, boolean

Why does EE `.expression('A?B:C') take into account C if A is always true?

I am using conditional operations with the `image.expression('condition ? true_action : false_action`) as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_relational). My understanding of the `A ? B : C` constructs is that it is a ternary operator, that says: if A is true, return B. Otherwise, if A is false, return C.

I expect hence that if is A is always true, C will never be evaluated. So if C returns a non-sensical answer (like log(-1)) that should not affect my result. This does not seem to be the case in earthEngine: if C is non-sensical, the overall result will be show up with *Masked pixel*. Indeed compare:

- `var expr_ok = ee.Image(3).expression(" 3 <4   ? 1 : 2")`: returns always 1
- `var expr_absurd = ee.Image(3).expression(" 3 <4   ? 1 : asin(2)")`: does not return anything (Masked)

Is my understanding of ternary operator wrong, or is that a bug/unexpected feature of EE? I am aware I could use the `image.where()` approach, but my question is specifically about the `.expression(A?B:C)` approach.

#### Minimal code

Here is a very simple case showing the issue (my real case is more complicated, where I want to evaluate asin(x) only if x in [-1, 1])).

```js
// different approaches 
var expr_ok = ee.Image(3).expression(" 3 <4   ? 1 : 2")
var expr_absurd = ee.Image(3).expression(" 3 <4   ? 1 : asin(2)")

var where_ok = ee.Image(3).where(ee.Image(3).lte(4), 1).where(ee.Image(3).gte(4), 2)
var where_absurd = ee.Image(3).where(ee.Image(3).lte(4), 1).where(ee.Image(3).gte(4), ee.Image(3).asin())


//visu 
var pal = {min: 1, max: 2, palette: ['0000FF', '00FF00', 'FF0000']}
Map.addLayer(expr_ok, pal, 'expr_ok', false);
Map.addLayer(expr_absurd, pal, 'expr_absurd');

Map.addLayer(where_ok, pal, 'where_ok', false);
Map.addLayer(where_absurd, pal, 'where_absurd', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not due to the expressions. It simply you cannot take the asin() from values outside the range [-1-1]. Possibly, the earth engine evaluates both possibilities and if one is wrong, it returns a masked image.

> Note: If the parameter x is outside the range -1 to 1, the browser will return NaN.

See: [Link to javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_asin.asp)

This example script shows that using asin(-2) returns a masked image while when using the same statement with asin(-1), it doesn't: [link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/75fb313fbe490bd10f16d170d2fbc2d9)

Thus, these should work:

```
// different approaches 
var expr_ok = ee.Image(3).expression(" 3 <4   ? 1 : 2")
var expr_absurd = ee.Image(3).expression(" 3 <4   ? 1 : asin(-1)")

var where_ok = ee.Image(3).where(ee.Image(3).lte(4), 1).where(ee.Image(3).gte(4), 2)
var where_absurd = ee.Image(3).where(ee.Image(3).lte(4), 1).where(ee.Image(3).gte(4), ee.Image(0.5).asin())
```

Comment: thanks! But my question is why it evaluates the `asin(-2)` when the expression is always true? Here it should never evaluate asin(-2): `3 <4   ? 1 : asin(-2)` but it seems it still does?

Comment: I think the GEE first evaluates the result of both and recognizes that there is a wrong argument in the expression. It does correct when your input are valid images.E.g. constructing an image using ee.Image(Math.asin(2)) results in an error.